# Adding options of select dynamically from array from java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 select input in my HTML page

```
<select id="parent">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

And

```
<select name="selectOpt" id="dmSelect">
<option disabled selected >-Select an Option-</option>
</select>
```

Now I need  add some option depending on the value of `parent`

suppose if `one` is selected options of `selectOpt` will be

```
<option value="a1">a1</option>
<option value="a2">a2</option>
```

and if `two` is selected options of `selectOpt` will be

```
<option value="b1">b1</option>
<option value="b2">b2</option>
```

and these options will come from some array
for like

```
A=["a1","a2"...]
B=["b1","b2"...]
```

Comment: i can get the selected value of `parent` using jquery and can append html to any element using ("#..").append().

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fpxqghj8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Arrays:

```
A=[{display: "a1", value: "a1" },
  {display: "a2", value: "a2" },
   ........
   ]

B=[{display: "b1", value: "b1" },
{display: "b2", value: "b2" },
 ........
 ]
```

Now on change

```
$('#parent').change(function() {
var parent = $(this).val();
$("#dmSelect").html("");`

switch(parent) {
    case 1:
        $(A).each(function (i) 
        { 
        $("#dmSelect").append("<option value=\""+A[i].value+"\">"+A[i].display+"           </option>");
        });

        break;
    case 2:
        $(B).each(function (i) 
        { 
        $("#dmSelect").append("<option value=\""+B[i].value+"\">"+B[i].display+"</option>");
        });

        break;
      default:
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this,

```
$('#parent').on('change', function(e) {
    var that = $(this).val();
    switch(that) {
        case 1:
            $("#dmSelect").append(
            $('<option/>', {
                value: a1,
                html: a1
            },{
                value: a2,
                html: a2
            })
            );
        });
            break;
        case 2:
            $("#dmSelect").append(
            $('<option/>', {
                value: b1,
                html: b1
            },{
                value: b2,
                html: b2
            })
            );
        });
            break;
        default:
            //default code block
    }
```

Comment: well this is helpful, no how can i set the values from and array like `A=["a1","a2"...]
B=["b1","b2"]`

Comment: @Saif, Array is like `A=["a1","a2"...]` use correct notation and Vaibhav has given you way forward, extend it for your requirement. What do you expect? If you want compelete work then hire some developers.

Comment: You can use your selected value from parent select element as an index to fetch values from your array, like A[that].. @Saif if you find my answer helpful then you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd do it with plain javascript:

```
<select id="parent" onChange="addOption()">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

then in script:

```
function addOption(){
  var e = document.getElementById("parent");
  var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

  if(strUser == 'One'){
     selecOpt = document.getElementById('dmSelect');

     var opt = document.createElement('option');
     opt.value = 'a1';
     opt.innerHTML = a1;
     selecOpt.appendChild(opt);

     opt = document.createElement('option');
     opt.value = 'a2';
     opt.innerHTML = a2;
     selecOpt.appendChild(opt);

  }
  else if(strUser == 'Two'){
     selecOpt = document.getElementById('dmSelect');

     var opt = document.createElement('option');
     opt.value = 'b1';
     opt.innerHTML = b1;
     selecOpt.appendChild(opt);

     opt = document.createElement('option');
     opt.value = 'b2';
     opt.innerHTML = b2;
     selecOpt.appendChild(opt);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to solve the problem yourself and if your stuck, we can help.

First you need to make a function that triggers on the change of the value of your select `change()`.
Then you need to get the value of this select `val()`.
Next you compare the value and depending of the value you `append()` your options to the next select.

If you try something first we can help you and you'll learn a lot more then just copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the sample code. Here I have appended new values. Instead of that by making ajax call you can get options values from db too.

$("#parent").on("change",function(){
if ( $(this).val() == "one")
{
var newValue = '<option value="b1">b1</option>';
newValue += '<option value="b2">b2</option>';
$("#dmSelect").append(newValue);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#parent").change(function () {
        var $dmSelect = $("#dmSelect");
        $dmSelect.empty().append("<option disabled selected >-Select an Option-</option>")
        if ($(this).find("option:selected").val() == "1") {
            $dmSelect.append("<option value='a1'>A1</option>")
                .append("<option value='a2'>A2</option>")
        } else if ($(this).find("option:selected").val() == "2") {
            $dmSelect.append("<option value='b1'>B1</option>")
                .append("<option value='b2'>B2</option>")
        } 
        /*other if elses*/


    }).change();
});
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/spcmLydq/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that you can easily adapt to your needs, reading the secondary options from some arrays.

JS:

```
//make one array from all your sub-arrays
var A = ['a1','a2','a3'];
var B = ['b1','b2'];
var arr = [A,B];

//grabs the first sub-array by default
$(function() {changeOpts(1);});

//changing the parent grabs the appropriate sub-array
$('#parent').on('change', function() {
    changeOpts($(this).val());
});

//forms a string with a bunch of <option> tags, then puts that inside #dmSelect    
function changeOpts(parentOpt) {
    var str = '<option disabled selected >-Select an Option-</option>';
    var arr2 = arr[parentOpt-1];
    var len = arr2.length;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        var value = arr2[i];
        str += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
    }
    $('#dmSelect').html(str);
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1fy120w9/1/).